# If I run find and replace all other cell that contain some other values go to #n/a

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup, find-replace

I want to change the values in this range

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Workbooks(Nextfile).Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1:Z171") = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup                                                                        (Workbooks(Nextfile).Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1:Z171"), _
                                                       ws.Range("A1:B2000"), _
                                                       2, False)
```

My problem is that when I run this all other cell that contain some other values go to #n/a.

What do I want my code to do:

Find all cells in `Workbook 1 - Sheet1` with values in range `("A1:Z171")` if the same value is found in `Workbook2 - Sheet2` range `("A1:B2000")` column `A` take value from column `B` of the same row and replace the value found in `Workbook 1 - Sheet1` in range `("A1:Z171")`.

Comment: You're looking to assess each cell individually to determine if it's found elsewhere... sounds like you need to loop through your data rather than mass-replace.

Comment: Ok, but how do I write that? ` Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
        Set rng = Workbooks(Nextfile).Sheets("Sheet").Range("A1:Z171")
        For Each cell In rng
            cell.Value = cell.Value & " " & cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            
        Next cell`?

Comment: For the future, please post code as an edit to your post... very difficult to ready/follow in the comments. You will need to do a check if the value exists to overwrite the cell value... this could be a `application.match` or a function that loops through the .lookup range.  Take a stab at adding the check and update your post to include your new info so we can help if you run into more issues.